# Using VTune for ROS profiling

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, All!
Can I use VTune Intel profiler for using in ROS? What are the basic steps to do it? In particular, how can I make symbolic information for VTune while ROS building? Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/337461/using-vtune-for-ros-profiling/) by [mikhail1981](https://answers.ros.org/users/49271/mikhail1981/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2019-11-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-12**:
Would you happen to know how to do this with CMake? If so: Catkin is a set of macros and functions for CMake. You should be able to just use the CMake workflow for VTune.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Couldn't use VTune in "launch application mode". But it wasn't any special to use it in "attach to process" mode (just building with debug configuration needed), and it worked fine. I think, question is not actual.

---

Originally posted by [mikhail1981](https://answers.ros.org/users/49271/mikhail1981/) with karma: 16 on 2019-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0